# How to assign a variable the current output of a select tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I'm having some trouble with a `select` tag.

I want to assign a value to a variable depending on which name is shown on the select tag:

```
<%= select('product', 'name' , @products.map { |s| [s.name, s.id] }, {}, {:class => "form-control"}) %>
```

The values display correctly, but I want to assign the currently selected value to a variable so that it can be used later on the same page to display content with the relevant details of the selected product.

For example:

```
@product = currently_displayed_name
```

Is this possible with Rails and how to do it? Or do I might need to use another resource?

Comment: You mean to ask, if it is possible to change value of a variable whenever the select field value is changed. So that you can display the value in the page?

Comment: Don't you already have access to @ product on the page. In which case you can just use @ product.name

Comment: @karina I had a typo on product.map it is products.map the variable product does not exist yet, I want to assign the value of the currently selected option.

Comment: @Alfie Not exactly I mean to create a new variable and assign the value to it.

Comment: @JorgeCuevas That would be something you would not be able to do with rails

Comment: If showing the current selected value somewhere in you page is what you need, you can use javascript/jquery for it

Comment: Well if this page has no product defined then it would just be @ products.first.name and if one is defined then it should be @ product.name. if you want the value after the page is rendered and after a user has interacted with it you will need to venture into javascript

Comment: @Alfie I was afarid so, thank you anyways.

Comment: @karina I imagined javascript might be the solution, but wanted to verify if I was missing something in rails, thank you a lot anyways.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I'd recommend reading http://catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html. It'll help you when asking questions.

Comment: @theTinMan Thanks for the tip! I'll give it a read. Everyone has been so helpful, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Props to the comments, the answer is that Rails **does not give you a way to do that**. Depending on what you need to manipulate when user changes select value, you might be able to find a JavaScript library for it.

Otherwise, you can load the default variable on the page, and then handle the rest with an `onchange` handler:

```
$('#product_name').change(function() {
  // perform actions on the page with javascript
});
```