# Rails reference related model id in a create form_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a `form_for` rails view which is set up like this:

```
 = form_for :school_application,  html: {id: :school_app } ,class: 'school_application' do |f|
```

I have a related model which I populate on this form called "program". I would like to do a find by Id of the Program model in another part of this same form, based on what the user inputs for the program parameter which is setup like this:

```
        = f.label :program
        = f.select(:program, Program.all.map{|p| [p.name, p.id]}, prompt: "Select a Program", selected:@school_application.program)
```

The problem is I can only reference a string version of the program name by doing:

```
:program
```

Which properly represent the right `programInstance.name` property. However, I would like capture the id of this related model within the same `form_for` once the program is selected. I know it is in there somewhere because when I submit the form my Rails output gives me:

```
  Started POST "/application/new" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-11-26 16:30:18 -0800
 Processing by SchoolApplicationsController#create as HTML


 Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>, "school_application"=>
{"family_name"=>"", "first_name"=>"", "address"=>"", "address_2"=>"", 
"city_state_province"=>"", "state_province"=>"", "postal_code"=>"", 
"country"=>"", "phone_number"=>"", "fax_number"=>"", "email"=>"", 
"gender"=>"", "date_of_birth"=>"", "country_of_citizenship"=>"", 
"country_of_birth"=>"",  "program"=>"2"}}
```

So i know its in there. Does anybody know how to access it within the .html.erb form?

This is how i try to access the program later on in the form:

```
  - if not params.nil? and not params['school_application'].nil? and Program.find(params['school_application']['program']).study_thirty_plus
      = f.label :study_thirty_plus
      = f.check_box :study_thirty_plus
```

`params` does not work, neither does `@program`. Only `:program` retains the right name, but since it is a symbol it does not have a property `.id`

I can do it this way, but it is a brittle solution since it assumes that Program names are always unique:

```
- if not :program.nil? and not Program.find_by_name(:program).nil? and Program.find_by_name(:program).study_thirty_plus
      = f.label :study_thirty_plus
      = f.check_box :study_thirty_plus
```

Comment: Are you saying that once the user has selected a program on the form, that program correctly shows up later in the form _before_ the user submits?
 Can you share where/how you are trying to then utilize the selected program later in the form?

Comment: that is correct

Comment: It sounds like you want that checkbox to appear once someone has selected a program. For that I recommend taking a look at what you can do with jQuery and AJAX to make the checkbox visible (e.g., you can wrap those two items in a div and attach an on-change to the select field).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My temporary solution was actually no solution at all, since I was working on a dataset where a `Program` instance was actually named `program` and thus `Program.find_By_name(:program)` worked in my case. After further research I realized that I shouldn't try to do reactive UI stuff with rails like this, but should use jQuery or some other javascript library to listen to changes in the DOM and then call a rake endpoint in that `.onChange()` block to do see if the program is `study_thirty_plus`.

This may also be a reference: 
[How to assign a variable the current output of a select tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36781540/how-to-assign-a-variable-the-current-output-of-a-select-tag)